# send post request forcefully on ember model save

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am currently trying to implement record duplication functionality. when I send request to server rather than creating a new record, it updates records. So is there any way to send a POST request forcefully? even if object has Dirty data or is there a way to set current record's isNew to true ?

Or you can say I want to send post request in ember with dirty record.

Answer (score 3):

If the request is sent and a PUT it means that the record is already saved.  You can simply create a copy of the existing one and save it (minus the id attribute of course) which will result in a POST.

```
var model = this.get('model');
var copy = this.store.createRecord('something', {
   propA = model.get('propA'),
   prompB = model.get('propB') 
});
copy.save.then(function() {
    alert('saved');
}).catch(function(reason) {
   console.log(reason);
});
```